# In python Django, I want to query a foreignKey coloumn of a table, it raise django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

I have a app name publisher. 
I run the code in publisher/views.py. 
It runs OK for inserting entries and newspapers = Newspaper.objects.values('newspaper_link')

Tables are OK when I view it in the SQLite DB Browser.
But when I run

```
newspapers = Newspaper.objects.values('country_id')
```

or

```
newspapers = Newspaper.objects.values()
```

It raise

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

Here is my publisher/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    country_link = models.URLField()
    country_name = models.TextField(primary_key=True)

class Newspaper(models.Model):
    newspaper_link = models.URLField(primary_key=True)
    newspaper_name = models.TextField()
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

Here is my traceback information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File     "D:/teamproject/DjangoProjectOne/DjangoProjectOne/mysite/publisher/views.py", line 99, in <module>
preOrder('a')
File "D:/teamproject/DjangoProjectOne/DjangoProjectOne/mysite/publisher/views.py", line 78, in preOrder
newspapers = Newspaper.objects.values()
File "C:\Users\Joy Zhang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Joy Zhang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 606, in values
return self._clone(klass=ValuesQuerySet, setup=True, _fields=fields)
File "C:\Users\Joy Zhang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 960, in _clone
c._setup_query()
File "C:\Users\Joy Zhang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1136, in _setup_query
self.query.add_fields(self.field_names, True)
File "C:\Users\Joy Zhang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1692, in add_fields
name.split(LOOKUP_SEP), opts, alias, allow_many=allow_m2m)
File "C:\Users\Joy Zhang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1466, in setup_joins
names, opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True)
File "C:\Users\Joy Zhang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1367, in names_to_path
if field.is_relation and not field.related_model:
File "C:\Users\Joy Zhang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 60, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\Joy Zhang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 110, in related_model
apps.check_models_ready()
File "C:\Users\Joy Zhang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Here is my INSTALLED_APPS in settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rss',
'tweet',
'publisher'
)
```

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rss',
    'tweet',
    'publisher',
)

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31654988/edit) button under your tags to update your question with new information. Also, the problem is probably more dependant on where you are actually using this line of code

Comment: What does `mysite/publisher/views.py`, vicinity of lines 78 and 99, look like? The error message states that you're trying to access Django models before Django has finished loading them. Based on that, I'm wondering if your views.py is trying to do something outside of any view functions (i.e., when the file is first loaded).

Comment: I had same problems after an upgrade. Have you upgraded Django?

Comment: How are you running it? Via webserver, or script?

Comment: It works when via webserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the traceback, you appear to be calling your `preOrder` function at module level. You don't say what that function is doing, but that is definitely the cause of your error. You should only call model methods from within views, or from functions called from a view.

Answer (score 0):

I get the exception when I run standalone views.py on pyCharm so the models are not registered.
And I add the following code and then it works

```
import os, sys
proj_path = "D:/teamproject/mysite"
# This is so Django knows where to find stuff.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
sys.path.append(proj_path)
# This is so my local_settings.py gets loaded.
os.chdir(proj_path)
# This is so models get loaded. 
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```